# Get text from an element of a web page with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing

I have this error: **Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string**

I'm trying to parse web page to get text inside a `div`

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$table = $dom->getElementById('mostra')> textContent; //DOMElement
echo $table;
```

This is html element:

```
<div id="mostra">Hello<img src="file.png"></div>
```

I want to print **Hello**

How can i solve it ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Comment: you seem to have a typo: `... )> textContent;` should be `...)-> textContent;`  - otherwise, your code should [work](https://3v4l.org/4QXud)

Answer (score 0):

```
function string_between_two_string($str, $starting_word, $ending_word) {
    $subtring_start = strpos($str, $starting_word);
    $subtring_start += strlen($starting_word);
    $size = strpos($str, $ending_word, $subtring_start) - $subtring_start; 
    return substr($str, $subtring_start, $size);
}

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);

$table = string_between_two_string($html, '<div id="mostra">', '<img src="file.png"></div>');
echo $table;
```

Try to use this function to find text between two element